# Check for empty String

Tags: string, vbscript

I want to know how it is possible to check for an empty string.

I created a SQL statement which selects some datas in my database.

```
qry_pkv = "SELECT DISTINCT MANDT, PATH301 FROM NC301B " & _
          "WHERE EDIPROC like 'P30_'" & _
          "AND (LF301M > 0) " & _
          "AND (PATH301 LIKE '%\pkv_dav\%') " & _
          "OR  (PATH301 LIKE '%\PKV_DAV\%');"
```

The statement works great but I don't know how to check if there is any value inside of `qry_pkv`.

```
rs.open qry_pkv, cn, 3

Zeile = "Skriptausfuehrung wird gestartet."
Call Trace (3, "I", Zeile)

If qry_pkv <> Null Then
    rs.MoveFirst

    ReDim Preserve AusgabeDir_pkv(0)

    i = 0

    Zeile = "PKV_DAV Verzeichnisse"                   'Überschrift für LOG-Datei.
    Call Trace (3, "@", Zeile)                        'Überschrift wird in LOG-Datei geschrieben.

    Do While Not rs.EOF                               'Schleife für durchsuchen der Datenbank.
        ReDim Preserve AusgabeDir_pkv(i)
        ReDim Preserve MANDT_pkv(i)
        AusgabeDir_pkv(i) = rs("DIRIN")               'Ausgabeverzeichnis wird in Variable gespeichert und verarbeitet.
        MANDT_pkv(i) = rs("MANDT")
        Zeile = "Verzeichnis in Bearbeitung: " & "MDT " & MANDT_pkv(i) & " PFAD " & AusgabeDir_pkv(i)  'Status der Verarbeitung.
        Call Writelog (Zeile)                         'Status wird in LOG-Datei geschrieben.
        ' call loeschen_gio(AusgabeDir_gio(i))        'Funktion löschen wird aufgerufen um Verzeichnis zu leeren wenn älter n Tage.

        i = i+1
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
Else
    Zeile = "PKV_DAV Verzeichnisse"                   'Ergebnis wird in LOG-Datei geschrieben.
    Call Trace (3, "@", Zeile)                        'Prozedur "WriteLog" wird aufgerufen
    Zeile = "Keine PKV_DAV Verzeichnisse vorhanden."  'Ergebnis wird in LOG-Datei geschrieben.
    Call Trace (3, "-", Zeile)                        'Prozedur "WriteLog" wird aufgerufen
End If
```

My plan was that the script is jumping to the `Else` statement in case of an empty `qry_pkv`.

Comment: try this `String.IsNullOrEmpty(qry_pkv); `

Comment: im getting an error. Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment: 'String'

Comment: But `qry_pkv` is your sql statement, how can it be null. I think what you need to check if if the recordset is empty or not. `If Not rs.EOF Then`

Comment: @SearchAndResQ that seems to be working. Thank u very much.

Comment: `"AND (PATH301 LIKE '%\pkv_dav\%') OR  (PATH301 LIKE '%\PKV_DAV\%');"` are the same if collation is case-insensitive or should be `"AND (PATH301 LIKE '%\pkv_dav\%' OR  PATH301 LIKE '%\PKV_DAV\%');"` if case-sensitive. Remove `OR` part or you will have `(cond1 and cond2 and cond3) or cond3`

Answer (score 1):

As [@SearchAndResQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38120409/check-for-empty-string/38121345#comment63674660_38120409) pointed out `qry_pkv` is your query string, so it's unlikely ot be `Null`. Check the cursor position in the recordset instead:

```
If Not rs.EOF Then
  ...
Else
  ...
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

`Null` is not the same as `Empty` is not the same as `""` (empty string). And a comparison `var <> Null` doesn't even work in the first place.

- Use the function [`IsNull`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zbchw6hz) to check for `Null` values.
- Use the function [`IsEmpty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cs4befa) to check for `Empty` values (mainly uninitialized variables). Comparisons with empty strings also cover `Empty` values, so if you want to distinguish between `Empty` and `""` you need to test for `Empty` values before testing for empty strings.
- Use regular [comparison operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hck4s70) to check for empty strings.

In your case you probably want something like this:

```
If qry_pkv <> "" Then
  ...
Else
  ...
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! qry_pk <> "" was my first idea too. But im getting the error "Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record. The Error is reffering to the line with the rs.MoveFirst command. The Source is ADODB.Recordset.

Comment: Use `WScript.Echo TypeName(qry_pkv)` to determine the actual type of the variable `qry_pkv`. It's either not a string, or it's not empty and your DB query didn't return results.

Answer (score 0):

Check the length of the string.  if it's <= 0, then you don't have the bolus of content you want in it:

```
If len(qry_pkv) <= 0 Then
   '//...the rest of your code
else
   '//...the else
end if
```

FYI, my habit is to use the three characters '// as my vbscript  comment because my eye skips over the ' alone.

see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42byt104(v=vs.84).aspx for more info on the Len() function.